# Multi row Mutation in Hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to use MultiRowMutationProtocol in Hbase as given here in this link.  http://hadoop-hbase.blogspot.in/2012_02_01_archive.html.

My codebase already uses `hbase-client`(`org.apache.hbase/hbase-client/0.98.11-hadoop1 0.98.11-hadoop2`).

This does not have the `MultiRowMutationProtocol class`.Is there a different way of using `MultiRowMutationProtocol using hbase-client`.

Or Is the Htable.batch , already taking care of it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mutation` implements `Row`, so you should be able to use `HTable.batch(List<Row>)`. I have successfully sent `batch` a list with a mixture of `Put`s, `Delete`s and `Increment`s.